# Writing logs to file using Xamarin.Forms and Serilog

Tags: android, xamarin, logging, xamarin.forms, serilog

Hello I am having trouble writing logs to file on Android device using Xamarin.Forms (.NET Core shared project) and Serilog.

So far I have installed Serilog in Shared project. Installed Serilog, Serilog.Sinks.File, and Serilog.Sinks.Xamarin to my Android project and initialized logger in MainActivity:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .WriteTo.File(Path.Combine(Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath,"XamarinLib-{Date}.txt"),
                        outputTemplate: "{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] [{SourceContext}] {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}",
                        fileSizeLimitBytes: 100000000,
                        rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                        rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                        shared: false,
                        retainedFileCountLimit: 31,
                        encoding: Encoding.UTF8)
                    .WriteTo.AndroidLog()
                    .CreateLogger();
```

Afterwards I call the logger from shared project like:

```
Log.Information("Test writing to log file");
```

I can see the log command being executed in Visual Studio debug output, but the file is simply not created. 
I've tried multiple locations on both emulator and actual device (no root access).

I've also tried to use RollingFile sink in similar manner with no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: hook the Serilog SelfLog to see the exceptions - chances are the issue is not serilog specific and instead related to whether boring .NET File  APIs can write where you are asking - try that with File.WriteAllText

Answer (score 3):

First, you have to allow permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Next, The user either must, approve that on runtime in which you have to code this in your code behind. ***NOTE Remember to add Plugin.Permissions on your NUGET package***:

```
       InitializeComponent();

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Storage);
                if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
                {
                        var accepted = await DisplayAlert("Storage Permission Required",
                            "Please enable your storage permission, it will be used to store logs and crashes",
                            "ACCEPT",
                            "CANCEL");
                        if(accepted)
                        {
                            var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(Permission.Storage);
                            status = results[Permission.Storage];
                        }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                await DisplayAlert("Exception ex", "Exception ex", "OK");
            }
        });
```

OR

let them change the permissions in the `settings -> app -> permissions.`

Finally, 
change the filename that will link to the `storage/emulated/0/[your added directory]`.

After the closing the app, you can see it in the Android File Manager.

Answer (score 1):

as pointed out by Ruben Bartelink the problem is that Android can't simply write to external storage (ie /storage/emulated/0... etc..).
I was able to log to a file on a Xamarin.Forms project in both Android and iOS.

```cs
_Tmp = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();            
_Path = System.IO.Path.Combine(_Tmp, "Serilog.txt");

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .MinimumLevel.Debug()
  .WriteTo.File(_Path, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, retainedFileCountLimit: 7)
  .CreateLogger();

Log.Information("Started new serilogger {SERILOG} on file {FILE}", this, _Path);

Log.CloseAndFlush();

//test
foreach (string log in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(_Tmp, "*.txt"))
{
    string test = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(log);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"Test[{log}] -> {test}");
}
```

which printed on the debug console:

```
    [0:] Test[/data/user/0/com.******/cache/Serilog20190819.txt] -> 2019-08-19 16:00:36.997 +02:00 [INF] Started new serilogger ******.Functions.Serilogger on file /data/user/0/com.******/cache/Serilog.txt
```

Comment: Hi @StefanoV, I would like to ask if you were able to find a way to open this file in File Manager of Android?

Comment: @PaulaKristin I wasn't able to open from Android File Manager, but I can share it from inside the application as email attachment. I think I read somewhere that the files are accessible via ADB (not sure)

Comment: I found a solution. Let me know if you want me to share it here as an answer. First you have to allow permissions in your Android Manifest file for storage. The user either must, approve that on runtime in which you have to code, or you have to let them change the permissions in the settings -> app -> permissions. Then, you have to change the filename that will link to the `storage/emulated/0/[your added drive]. After the closing the app, you can see it in the Android File Manager.

Comment: Yes @PaulaKristin, a working sample would be useful.

Comment: Done, let me know what you guys think and please check if it works.